# Is this possible to have optional SSM parameter?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Is the following valid in a cloudformation template:

```
Parameters:
  ParameterA:
    Default: ''
    NoEcho: false
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<List<String>>
```

Because the template is validated successfully but cloudformation return the following when I try to create the stack without providing ParameterA:

> Parameter ParameterA should either have input value or default value

I want to have an SSM parameter that is optional because it is used in by a resource that is created upon certain condition.

Comment: Maybe the empty string is a problem. Try `AWS::NoValue` instead

Comment: I tried to use AWS::NoValue but CF said I do not have the permission to retrieve the parameter. 

I found a workaround that seems ok for now. I create parameters for empty values (string and list) and use their key name as default value for SSM parameters. I do have to put some 'null' value string in these parameters because I cannot create parameters with no value. I then use Condition to compare the value of the parameter with the 'null' value string.

Comment: It's not supported but there are workarounds https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260162/cloudformation-typed-parameter-that-can-be-empty

Comment: @kichik Those workarounds don't work because `AWS::SSM::Parameter` types are validated at the beginning of a stack create or update event

Answer (score 0):

Technically no, but there is a way to almost achieve what you're after.

What follows is a pattern that I use for optional instance type overrides in launch templates or autoscaling groups etc.

When we're not using specific parameters, then need to exist (otherwise you'll get a CFN error), but we initialize them all to `unused` (or some other value).

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >
  Demo optional parameters
  
Parameters:
  ParameterA:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: /mystack/ParameterA

Conditions:
  ParameterA: !Not [!Equals ['unused', !Ref ParameterA]]

Resources:
  ConditionalResource:
    Condition: ParameterA
    Type: AWS::...
    Properties:
       Parameter: !Ref ParameterA

  ConditionalProperty:
    Type: AWS::...
    Properties:
       Name: Some resource
       Parameter: !If [ParameterA, !Ref ParameterA, !Ref AWS::NoValue]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve your objective by so:

```
Parameters:
  ParameterA:
    Default: ''
    Type: String

Conditions:
  toCreateResourceA: !Not [!Equals [!Sub '${ParameterA}', '']]

Resources:

  #Use Case 1: Only create resource if ParameterA exists
  ResourceA:
    Condition: toCreateResourceA 
    Type: AWS::xx
    Properties:
      #Use Case 2: Configure value if ParameterA exists
      PropertyA: !If [toCreateResourceA, !Sub "{{resolve:ssm:${ParameterA}}}", !Ref AWS::NoValue]
      ...
```

Comment: This does not answer the question - the question is about an optional SSM Parameter, not using a condition to create a resource.