# Conditional value of ssm parameter in cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloudformation template that uses a few ssm parameters.
Those parameters are only defined in a given region for a given account.
I would like to use the ssm parameters if they are defined and not use them if they are not defined in a given region (perhaps default to a certain string value like "undefined").

Something like this

```
Parameters:
  anssmparameter:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    # if ssmparam is defined
    Default: ssmparam
    # else ssmparam is not defined use a different default
    Default: "a placeholder value"
    Description: some description
```

Is this possible in cloudformation? I have researched a bit and it seems this is not possible?

The close I have seen is this which essentially says it is not possible

[Is this possible to have optional SSM parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55011681/is-this-possible-to-have-optional-ssm-parameter#)

Comment: You can set a default value for CloudFormation parameters. CloudFormation also provides [Condition function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html), like `Fn::If`. Probably you could combine these two reach to a solution.

Comment: Do you have any template code to show demonstrating what do you want to do?

Comment: @Marcin I added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you **can't have** conditions in `Parameters`, unless you write a tin wrapper around your deployment procedure which would modify the template before it goes to CloudFormation.

Other then that, you would have to use `If` conditions in `Resources` to actually alternate between different possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic references to resolve on runtime if given parameter value

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html

```
Parameters:
  anssmparameter:
    Type: String
  placeholdervalue:
    Type: String
    Default: 'a placeholder value'

Conditions:
  toResolveSSMParam: !Not [!Equals [!Sub '${anssmparameter}', '']]

Resources:
  ResourceA:
    Properties:
      PropertyA: !If [toResolveSSMParam, !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:${anssmparameter}}}', !Ref placeholdervalue]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).